# How to autocrop randomly using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, crop

I'm trying to write a script in PIL that basically creates a bunch of images out of a larger image.
I want to take a larger image, let's say it's 1000X1000 pixels, and crop squares of 250x250 out of it at "random" locations.

I know that .crop(box) exists and works one image and one crop at a time. Is there any way I can use this to do the task I want?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the squares you extract?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm going to use the squares as training images for my ML model

Comment: Do you care whether the edges are underrepresented in the sampling?

Comment: I do, I'd like to get edges in as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
from PIL import Image
from random import randrange

img = Image.open(r"image_path")  
x, y = img.size

matrix = 250
sample = 10
sample_list = []

for i in range(sample):
    x1 = randrange(0, x - matrix)
    y1 = randrange(0, y - matrix)
    sample_list.append(img.crop((x1, y1, x1 + matrix, y1 + matrix)))
```

***matrix =>*** Size of the matrix that would be used for cropping (has to be symmetric & should be smaller then the image size by a considerable amount)

***sample =>*** Number of samples that must be taken (or the number of cropped images)

***sample_list =>*** The list the would be used to store the cropped images

- After the execution of the code, `sample_list` will contain several image objects which could be individually referenced by their index numbers (*ex.* `sample_list[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

a small adaptation of @Vasu answer, added margin crop if needed (if margins are not important) and set matrix based on image height / width. Can be adapted to your needs.

```
from random import randrange
from PIL import Image

def autocrop(pil_img, pct_focus=0.3, matrix_HW_pct=0.3, sample=1):
    """
    random crop from an input image
    Args:
        - pil_img
        - pct_focus(float): PCT of margins to remove based on image H/W
        - matrix_HW_pct(float): crop size in PCT based on image Height
        - sample(int): number of random crops to return
    returns:
        - crop_list(list): list of PIL cropped images
    """
    x, y = pil_img.size
    img_focus = pil_img.crop((x*pct_focus, y*pct_focus, x*(1-pct_focus), y*(1-pct_focus)))
    x_focus, y_focus = img_focus.size
    matrix = round(matrix_HW_pct*y_focus)
    crop_list = []
    for i in range(sample):
        x1 = randrange(0, x_focus - matrix)
        y1 = randrange(0, y_focus - matrix)
        cropped_img = img_focus.crop((x1, y1, x1 + matrix, y1 + matrix))
        #display(cropped_img)
        crop_list.append(cropped_img)
    return crop_list
```